# How do I adjust my layout?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I am moving from Android to IOS, and am following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1) tutorial. The problem is that my layout is not adaptive, as should be the default. The tutorial shows the layout to be like so:

[image]

However, my layout is not adaptive (universal) for both iPad and iPhone, and the UI is only that of an iPhone:

[image]

I searched a lot on why my layout is not universal (it should be by default), and most of the results said I need to enable Size Classes.

**For me, however, the option to enable Size Classes isn't even there, I have the options:**

- Use Auto Layout
- Use trait variations
- Use as launch screen

How do I make my storyboard adaptive and enable Size Classes?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: just continue tutorial it will work or find tutorial for swift 3.0. It is adaptive you did not even try just assume somethig :)

Comment: @Lu_ Adaptive to even iPad? The tutorial continues to assume that the layout is adaptive.

Comment: The way in which you preview scenes and select size traits has changed in Xcode 8.  Whether an app is universal or not is selected in the solution settings, not in the storyboard.  When you created your app, if you selected "universal" then it will be a universal app

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay, that makes sense. I'm not sure if I had selected universal when I created the app, is there any way to check now and make sure it is universal? Thanks

Comment: Yes, just select your project in the navigator and look on the general page (first page)

Comment: It is listed against "devices" on that page

Answer (score 0):

I think your UI is adaptive, it's just that in Xcode 8 the storyboard shows the UI in whatever device you have selected. If you look at the bottom of your screen in storyboard view it's says iPhone 6s, click that and you can select to view as a different device (iPad included). So even though it doesn't look like it, it should be adaptive.

As a side note size classes are only for if you want the UI to be different between devices, not adaptive.